# Poruqe me sale este error? ([Error] expected primary-expression before '/' token)

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int opcion, num;
    float numero, cubo;
    
    cout<<"\t.:MENU:."<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Cubo de un numero"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Numero par o impar"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"Opcion: ";
    cin>>opcion;
    
    switch(opcion){
        case 1: cout<<"\nDigite un numero: ";
                cin>>numero;
                cubo = pow(numero,3);
                cout<<"\nEl cubo del numero es: "<<cubo<<endl;
                break
        case 2: cout<<"\nDigite un numero: ";
                cin>>num;
                if (num%2==0){
                cout<<"\nEl numero es par";<<endl;
            }
        
            else{
                cout<<"El numero no es par"<<endl;
            }
                break;
        case 3: break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Me nsale este error en la opcion 2  ([Error] expected primary-expression before '/' token) por favor ayudenme yo no logro ver cual es el error

Comment: Te falta un `;` después de un `break`, y te sobra un `;` después de las comillas del mensaje `"\nEl numero es par"`.

Answer (score 1):

Hola tienes varios errores de sintaxis, el primero es en el primer break ahi falto un ; y el segundo en el case 2 al final del cout colocaste `cout << ""; << cosa;` que no es valida en C++  deberia ser algo asi

```
cout << "mensaje" << cosa;
```

aqui tienes el codigo sin estos dos errores, saludos y mucha suerte en tu camino de programacion

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>


   using namespace std;

int main(){
    int opcion, num;
    float numero, cubo;
 


cout<<"\t.:MENU:."<<endl;
cout<<"1. Cubo de un numero"<<endl;
cout<<"2. Numero par o impar"<<endl;
cout<<"3. Salir"<<endl;
cout<<"Opcion: ";
cin>>opcion;

switch(opcion){
    case 1: cout<<"\nDigite un numero: ";
            cin>>numero;
            cubo = pow(numero,3);
            cout<<"\nEl cubo del numero es: "<<cubo<<endl;
            break;
    case 2: cout<<"\nDigite un numero: ";
            cin>>num;
            if (num%2==0){
            cout<<"\nEl numero es par"<<endl;
        }
    
        else{
            cout<<"El numero no es par"<<endl;
        }
            break;
    case 3: break;
    }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Gracias, si era eso

Comment: Gracias muy amable